# Prolonging the continuity of $g$

Tags: limits, continuity

I have a doubt. If

$$g(x,y) =\frac{(\sin(xy))}{(x+y)}$$

it's possible to prolong the continuity of this function to all points of the frontier of $g$?

I know that I can prolong it to the origin if $(0,0)$ was the only point of the frontier but I do not know how I can resolve the fact that the frontier includes the line $y=-x$.
I calculate the limit as the function approach $(0,0)$ with $x=0$ or $y=0$ and I find that the limit was $0$.

The problem is with the line $y=-x$. I was thinking that I could use some succession to approach $(0,0)$ with values closer and closer of the line $y=-x$. If the limit is the same I can prolong the continuity, otherwise it's not possible.

Can anyone help me?

Best regards

Comment: You need to specify the domain where $g$ is defined. What is $G$ exactly?

Comment: R^2 \{(0,0) and y=-x}

Comment: Then please add this to your question. And have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation .